# How to export class instance in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

Let's say, i have a class instance

```
const User = require(./User);

const id = '123456',
secret   = '8787';

const user = new User(id, secret)

module.exports = user;
```

The problem is that whenever i import `user`, it just returns an empty object.
Why is this occurring and what should i do in this case?

This is what i'm using for testing

***index.js file***

```
const OAuthClient = require('disco-oauth'); //class disco-oauth

const credential = require('./credential.json');

//class instance
const oauthclient = new OAuthClient(credential.id,credential.secret); 

console.log(oauthclient); //Working fine in here

module.exports = oauthclient; //exporting instance
```

***test.js file***

```
const oauthclient = require('./index')
console.log(oauthclient) //prints {}
```

Comment: What is `User` that you are requiring in your file? Also, how are you importing the generated `user`?

Comment: This is just an example code, but in reality i'm using [disco oauth library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/disco-oauth) .

Comment: Try `console.log(user)` just bellow `const user = new User(id, secret)`. Does it print what you expect?

Comment: `const user = require(./user)` This is how i'm importing it. @mgarcia

Comment: yes, it is working that way.  @mgarcia

Comment: i've updated the code @mgarcia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My node server is running in `index.js` file and i was trying to export the class instance from that file, that's why it didn't work.

***Previous code***

```
const http =  require('http'),
bodyparser = require('body-parser'),
OAuthClient = require('disco-oauth');

const app = require('./Api/api');    
const credential = require('./credential.json');

const oauthClient = new OAuthClient(credential.id, credential.secret);
oauthClient.setScopes(['identify', 'guilds', 'connections']);           
oauthClient.setRedirect(credential.redirect);


app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyparser.json())

const server = http.createServer(app),
PORT         = 80;

server.listen(PORT,'0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log(`running on port ${PORT}`);
})

module.exports = {
    oauthClient
}
```

I removed `OAuthClient` from `index.js` and moved it in separate file and it's working now.

Answer (score 4):

you should make file with name `User.js` and copy this code :

```
class user {
    constructor(id, secret){
        this.id= id,
        this.secret=secret
    }
 }

 module.exports = user;
```

and your file is ok for require User class (yourFile.js)

```
const User = require(./User);

const id = '123456',
secret   = '8787';

const user = new User(id, secret)

module.exports = user;
```

and you can make `test.js` file for import this user (yourFile.js) :

```
const user = require('./yourFile.js')
console.log(user)
```

Comment: `class user`, `require` as `User`, and new instance as `user`? Sounds like a bad idea to flip flop the names.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in how you export your class, 
seems like you used `module.export = User` instead of `module.exports= User`

Comment: No, i'm using `module.exports`

Comment: They are not trying to export the class, they are trying to export an instance of the class.